# Access to a QQmlApplicationEngine inside my custom class

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing a Media Player in `Qt` using `QML`, I am making a `Qlist` of songs available in a directory and I want to send this list as a model to QML file, but I don't know how to access an engine declared in main inside my custom class `Player`.

So, there's my `main.cpp`

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QApplication app(argc, argv);

qmlRegisterType<Player>("io.qt.examples.player", 1, 0, "Player");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

Player player;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("player", &player); // this works fine

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;


return app.exec();
```

Inside my `Player` class I want to set another property, and I have found this code to help:

```
QQmlContext *currentContext = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this); // debugger says it's null
QQmlEngine *engine = currentContext->engine(); // Segmentation fault
```

I am getting a Segmentation fault error when debugger reaches this line, I have properly set a `QStringList` with names of files and want to do this:

```
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("listModel", QVariant::fromValue(files));
```

And I want to use this model there:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    model: listModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        Text {
            text: modelData
        }
    }
}
```

But getting also a QML error: `ReferenceError: listModel is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377676/how-can-i-display-a-qstringlist-in-c-to-a-qml-listview), changing my approach and switching my QStringList model to a Q_PROPERTY

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the question as best as I can without a complete example.

> I am getting a Segmentation fault error when debugger reaches this line

The problem is likely that the type is not constructed by the engine. The [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#contextForObject) say:

> When the QQmlEngine instantiates a QObject, the context is set automatically.

So you probably need to [set the context manually](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#setContextForObject). Usually this is done by using the context from an object that you know was constructed by the engine:

```
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(this, qmlContext(someQmlObject))
```

> But getting also a QML error: ReferenceError: listModel is not defined

Again, I don't have access to a complete example so I can only guess, and my guess would be that you set the context property too late. Context properties should be set before the QML that uses them is loaded.

---

What I would suggest though, is that you don't set context properties, and instead create a [proper model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass) and register it as a type that can then be instantiated in QML.

For more information about the various approaches to C++ and QML integration, take a look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html#choosing-the-correct-integration-method-between-c-and-qml).